# Need a easy way to extract Emails from the columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL In have a table of called chad which has Emails

but Emails are in single row separated by commas

Example

row 1

dom@uc.org,dorym@uc.org,dug@uc.org,dud@uc.org,ebbj@ucc.org,eeryk@ucc.org,flor@uc.org,feyl@ucc.org,frht@ucc.org,fyb@uc.org,garc@ucc.org,lesg@ucc.org,edeb@sobal.net,mllj@uc.org

row 2

fdfdflor@ucc.org,feyl@uc.org,freht@ucc.org,fyb@uc.org,gafgfrc@ucc.org,legfgfsg@uc.org,edrtreb@sal.net,mlgfglj@uc.org

I have cleaned and extracted most of the emails by using sql, the technique I was using was to create a new table every time and insert the data in that table by removing first email from previous table i have created before that.

```
create table chad
select right(`Email`, Length(Email) - Length(substring_index(Email,',',1))-1)  Email from chac;

insert into ch(Email)
select distinct Email from chac where Email not like '%,%';

delete c.* from Chac c JOIN CH ON C.email = CH.Email;

insert into ch(Email)
select distinct substring_index(Email,',',1) Email from chac;
```

the technique i was using was very laborious, is there a smart way of extracting emails. or some software that can do it for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have long list of things.  Here is one way to extract them:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(email, ',', n.n), ',', -1)
from (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n join
     chac c
     on (length(c.email) - length(replace(c.email, ',', '')) + 1) <= n.n;
```

You can then insert this into another table using `insert into` or `create table as`.

The expression:

```
length(c.email) - length(replace(c.email, ',', '')) + 1
```

counts the number of emails in the list, by counting the number of commas and adding 1.  The expression in the `select` extracts the nth element from the list.

You need to extend the `n` subquery to the maximum number of values needed for your particular lists.  If you don't type well, you can write the code as formulas in Excel (or another spreadsheet), copy them down, and insert them into your query tool.